# Creating BinaryWriter in a loop gets better performance than creating it once?

Tags: c#, performance

I examined memory mapped files to check their performance effect and while doing it I noticed, that if I recreate BinaryWriter, every time I'm going to write to file, it makes my code run 30% faster.

Would anyone have an explanation?

***This code runs 30% faster than the one below:***

```
 using (MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen("testmap", 1000000000))
 {
    DateTime dt;
    bool mutexCreated;
    Mutex mutex = new Mutex(false, "testmapmutex", out mutexCreated);
    using (MemoryMappedViewStream stream = mmf.CreateViewStream())
    {
       dt = DateTime.Now;
       for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
       {
           BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream); // In or out?
           try
           {
               mutex.WaitOne();
               writer.Write(i);
               mutex.ReleaseMutex();
           }
       }
    }
 }
```

***This code runs 30% slower than the one above:***

```
 using (MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen("testmap", 1000000000))
 {
    DateTime dt;
    bool mutexCreated;
    Mutex mutex = new Mutex(false, "testmapmutex", out mutexCreated);
    using (MemoryMappedViewStream stream = mmf.CreateViewStream())
    {
       dt = DateTime.Now;
       BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream); // In or out?
       for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
       {
           try
           {
               mutex.WaitOne();
               writer.Write(i);
               mutex.ReleaseMutex();
           }
       }
    }
 }
```

***Edit:***

Code should compile now.

***New observations:***

If I'm compiling in "Release" (instead debug) the problem is gone and results makes sense
When running the code on server with W2008 (instead of on PC with W7) problem is gone and results make sense

Comment: What you've posted wouldn't compile, please provide a more complete example. Also (assuming `dt` is intended for doing the timing) use `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` to perform your timings.

Comment: Aso, you aren't disposing the writer; that could mean here is unfleshed buffered data left in the writer.

Comment: Using the Mutex that often means you are not testing BinaryWriter - you are testing the Mutex performance.

Answer (score 2):

I have tested your code and it runs as follows. Used `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` to measure elapsed time.

> `BinaryWriter` within the loop: **4815537** ticks 
>   `BinaryWriter` outside the loop : **4168415** ticks

This is the expected normal behavior.

But having said that since you are not disposing `BinaryWriter` after instantiating within the `for` loop you are committing a grave mistake. If you correct that mistake then your code **won't run**.

**Wrong code**

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
   using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream)) 
   // this will force disposing of writer, but will also close the base 
   // stream instance too. 
   {
           // In or out?
           try
           {
              mutex.WaitOne();
              writer.Write(i);
              mutex.ReleaseMutex();
           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(e);
           }
    }
 }
```